# Update nested record with where condition in Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a bigquery table '**metrics**' which has nested record fields One of the fields is called **resource.labels** which has key pair values as shown below[image]

I need to the update resource.labels which is a repeated record field and has a key value pair resource.labels.key and resource.labels.value on this condition

```
where key="machinetype" and value="N/A" set value="g1.small"
```

I have tried this

```
update `metrics` set resource.labels.value=ARRAY(SELECT AS STRUCT * REPLACE("g1.small" as value) from UNNEST(resource.labels) as h where h.key="machinetype" and h.value="N/A") where resource.labels.key="machinetype" and resource.labels.value="N/A"
```

but gives this error:

```
Cannot access field key on a value with type ARRAY<STRUCT<key STRING, value STRING>> at [1:241]
```

can anyone give any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below- should work

```
UPDATE `project.dataset.metrics`
SET resource = (
    SELECT AS STRUCT * REPLACE(
      ARRAY(
        SELECT AS STRUCT key, 
          IF(key='machinetype' and value='N/A', 'g1.small', value) as value
        FROM t.labels
      ) AS labels)
    FROM UNNEST([resource]) t
  )
WHERE true
```

Comment: Excellent answer, i was thinking till yesterday how to update only those specific rows, but this solution is better